# How to access dependency resolver in ASP.NET WebAPI in external library

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I am designing a NuGet package that will be consumed by my application. Due to the project's already implemented architecture, I need to provide a way to instantiate objects using dependency injection both for MVC and Web API outside my controller scope.
Currently I have a class that works in MVC projects, by instantiating objects using the DependencyResolver

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> where T : class
  {
    public static T Instance
    {
      get
      {
          return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<T>();
      }
    }
  }
```

However, when consuming this same class from a WebAPI project, the DependencyResolver is not present, so Im not able to retrieve any object.

I have tried to access the dependency resolver via the HttpContext but have been unsuccessfull. Do you have any way I can access it through a NuGet package?

Thanks!

Comment: Asp.Net-MVC and Asp,Net-Web-API use different Dependency Resolvers even though they share the same name. You'll need to research them to understand their differences.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why the service locator pattern is usually a bad idea. It ties you to the implentation of a specific DI framework. Is it possible for you to use constructor injection here instead?

Comment: Thanks, I am aware that both MVC and WebAPI use different Dependency Resolvers. My problem is that the only one accessible is the MVC one and not the WebAPI. I know that this is a bad idea, however due to this being a legacy system I want to allow the original developers to continue using the Instance abstract property to access new functionality

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, I'd suggest avoid the service locator pattern and inject the dependency through the constructor instead:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> where T : class
{
    public MyBaseClass(T instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
    }

    public T Instance { get; }
}
```

This will allow you to use your package through any "main" entry point (e.g. MVC or WebAPI) that you choose. At that point, it would be the responsibility of the consumer to provide the necessary dependency resolution strategy.

---

Here's an example of how a consumer (in this case a WebAPI service) of the package would implement the above code:

```
public class MyWebApiClass : MyBaseClass<MyDependency>
{
    public MyWebApiClass(MyDependency resolvedDependency) : base(resolvedDependency) { }
}

public class MyDependency
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public MyDependency()
    {
        Foo = "Bar";
    }
}
```

Then the consuming service would also register those dependencies:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.AddTransient<MyDependency>();
    services.AddTransient<MyWebApiClass>();
}
```

... and inject as needed, allowing the framework to resolve the dependencies (IoC at work):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyWebApiClass _myWebApiClass;

    public ValuesController(MyWebApiClass myWebApiClass)
    {
        _myWebApiClass = myWebApiClass;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { _myWebApiClass.Instance.Foo };
    }
}
```

Making a call to the GET endpoint above, we can see our instance being resolved in `MyBaseClass`:

[image]

Comment: While the general concept of this answer is correct, the consumer code is for asp.net core while, based on the fact that the OP refers to DependencyResolver, that platform in question is most likely targeting asp.net-mvc-5+/asp.net-web-api-2+

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that this is possible, however I want to make this component accessible not only through main entry points i.e. controllers or filters, but through a static property in a class.

Comment: @Luis, you cant, and shouldnt do what you're trying to do. Resolution of dependencies is the responsibility of the Composition Root (or in this case, the other project that is calling your nuget package). You really need to remove your ServiceLocator Pattern code from your nuget package. The short answer is, rethink your architecture for your nuget package OR ditch the idea of trying to use IOC for it

Comment: Thanks, I ended up ditching the idea alltogether, as the other project's architecture wouldnt allow me to integrate IOC